# how do I store aspnet core app in Nexus Repository

Tags: asp.net-core, nexus

I have installed Nexus Repository in Local server and successfully uploaded nupkg files (dependencies). Now I'm trying to save my build (asp net core app buid dlls) in Nexus respo(Nexus hosted Repo type) and I'm unable to do it. 
Instead of storing asp net core build dlls directly in Nexus, do I have any workarounds.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Details are missing in problem statement.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to use it. Nexus is used for java dependencies, right? Instead, you can have a internal nugget to server your dependecies.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Alan. As we are a one team (Java, .NET) we are using  same tools in CI/CD pipeline. I have solved it, may be not the best way to do it. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a "row" type nuget in the nexus and uploaded zipped file in there which solved the issue. Here are the steps I have been taken.

1. publish project
   dotnet publish  -c Release -o
2. zip result
   winrar a -afzip myzip.zip
3. upload zip file to the Nexus
   curl --upload-file myzip.zip -u admin:admin123 -v http://172.99.99.99:8081/repository/nuget-release/
4. Done !!!